# Scaling data with negative range to values between 0 and 1

Tags: image, algorithm

I have prepared a feature which I want to use as an input to a deep classifier, and its value ranges from -1 to 1.

I want to use a sigmoid function on this data; how can I map this data to a range from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Examples of sigmoid-like functions that maps X range -1..1 to Y range 0..1:

Y = (X<sup>1/3</sup> + 1) / 2

Y =  (Sin(X*Pi/2) + 1) / 2